# Counting bit strings of length $70$ with two restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations, bit-strings

There is a bit string of length $70$. 
At least one of the following restrictions must apply:

i)The first $9$ bits cannot contain exactly $5$ 1s

ii)The first $49$ bits cannot contain exactly $27$ 1s.

How many combinations are there?

My first instinct is to do the following:
$2^{70}$ and subtract some number of combinations.

I am not sure how to go about this or if there is a more elegant way.
I am currently getting the following result, but I am not confident in it because I believe that there may be some double counting:

$2^{70}-(\binom{9}{5}+\binom{49}{27})=$

$997,056,092,945,595,000,000$

Comment: Do you mean that the first $9$ bits cannot contain exactly $5$ 1s or at least $5$ 1s?  Likewise, do you mean that the first $49$ bits cannot contain exactly $27$ 1s or at least $27$ 1s?

Comment: Yes exactly that amount so the first $9$ bits can contain anything other than $5$ 1's the same rule applies for the first 49 bits as well

Comment: Showing how you arrived at that number would make it easier for readers of this question to determine if you made an error.

Comment: A point of clarification:  Are the bad cases those in which exactly $5$ 1s appear in the first $9$ bits *and* exactly $27$ 1s appear in the first $49$ bits or those in which exactly $5$ 1s appear in the first $9$ bits *or* exactly $27$ 1s appear in the first $49$ bits?

Comment: it would be considered as an inclusive or, one or the other or both

Answer (score 3):

Your instinct is good.  However, you have not counted the bad cases correctly.

As you observed, there are $2^{70}$ possible bit strings.  From these, we must subtract those bit strings in which the first $9$ bits contain exactly $5$ 1s or those in which the first $49$ bits contain exactly $27$ ones.

Bit strings of length $70$ in which the first $9$ bits contain exactly $5$ ones:  There are $\binom{9}{5}$ ways to select which $5$ of the first $9$ bits are filled with 1s.  There are $2^{61}$ ways to fill the remaining $61$ bits.  Hence, there are 
$$\binom{9}{5}2^{61}$$
such bit strings.

Bit strings of length $70$ in which the first $49$ bits contain exactly $27$ ones:  There are $\binom{49}{27}$ ways to select which $27$ of the first $49$ bits are filled with 1s.  There are $2^{21}$ ways to fill the remaining $21$ bits.  Hence, there are 
$$\binom{49}{27}2^{21}$$
such bit strings.

Notice that if we subtract these numbers from the total, we will have subtracted those cases in which exactly $5$ of the first $9$ bits and exactly $27$ of the first $49$ bits are 1s twice.  We only want to subtract such cases once, so we need to add them back.

Bit strings of length $70$ in which exactly $5$ of the first $9$ bits and exactly $27$ of the first $49$ bits are 1s:  There are $\binom{9}{5}$ ways to select which $5$ of the first $9$ bits are filled with 1s.  If there are also exactly $27$ 1s in the first $49$ bits, then $27 - 5 = 22$ of the next $49 - 9 = 40$ must be filled with 1s.  The remaining $21$ bits can be filled in $2^{21}$ ways.  Hence, there are 
$$\binom{9}{5}\binom{40}{22}2^{21}$$
such cases.

Hence, by the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), the number of admissible bit strings is 
$$2^{70} - \binom{9}{5}2^{61} - \binom{49}{27}2^{21} + \binom{9}{5}\binom{40}{22}2^{21}$$